# How to protect an expensive backpack in airplane hold?

Tags: luggage, tips-and-tricks, gear

Last year I bought a nice osprey backpack and I stupidly (after removing loose straps) put the bag through check in without wrapping it up in cling film or whatever. and it got a bit damaged by way of a cut into the fabric.

what is the best way to protect an expensive backpack in airplane luggage? I have to use it as my main way of carrying luggage as its too big to warrante taking 2 large bags.

Any tips? E.g. on the flight back I put this backpack inside a cheap quechua dry bag with rucksack straps which protected it but it was a tight squeeze and a pain to get everything in.

Cling film wrapping seems to be an obvious option but looks like a pain in the ass.

Comment: I <3 baggage handler stickers.